# Splitting ETH when transferring

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity

I would be very grateful if you can help me with this simple question!

I want to make a split of funds in a smart contract: 10% will go to my friend and 90% will go to me. I created a variable and wrote the following code in the withdraw () function:

```
address private constant _friend = 0xAb8483F64d9C6d1EcF9b849Aeblablalbasomeaddress;
```

In the beginning of contract and:

```
function withdraw() public payable onlyOwner {
    uint balance = address(this).balance;
    payable(msg.sender).transfer(balance / 100 * 10);
    payable(_friend).transfer(balance / 100 * 90);
}
```

I tested this on a testnet, but i'm a little paranoid.  Will this code work?

Why do I think there might be problems with this?
When sending ETH, you have to pay a commission, so if I send msg.sender, then I send this 90% + commission, will I have enough money to send 10%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
payable(msg.sender).transfer(balance / 100 * 10);
payable(_friend).transfer(balance / 100 * 90);
```

This will work as expected for amounts (in wei) that are divisible by 100. Amounts not divisible by 100 will result in rounding errors, because you're dealing with division of **integers** (not decimals). So either of you could get a little less than expected.

Example:

- `balance` = 200 wei

  - `msg.sender` gets (200 / 100) * 10 = (2) * 10 = 20
  - `_friend` gets (200 / 100) * 90 = (2) * 90 = 180
- `balance` = 150 wei

  - `msg.sender` gets (150 / 100) * 10 = (1) * 10 = 10
  - `_friend` gets (150 / 100) * 90 = (1) * 90 = 90
  - The remaining 60 wei stays on contract address

Solidity resolves both operators from the left. So first it calculates `balance / 100` and then multiplies the result by `10` or `90`.

---

> *When sending ETH, you have to pay a commission*

You probably mean the gas fee. This is paid on top of the transaction `value` by the address executing the `withdraw()` function. The gas fee **does not** affect the internal transactions (and their `value`) that will be generated by each of the `transfer()` functions.

Example:

1. You are sending 1 ETH (or `1000000000000000000` wei) `value` along with the transaction executing the `withdraw()` function. The gas fee is 0.001 ETH, so the total amount you pay is 1.001 ETH. However, the fee goes to the network, so the contract still receives only the `value` of 1 ETH.
2. Then it gets split into the two internal transactions - 0.1 ETH to you (as the `msg.sender`) and 0.9 ETH to the `_friend` address. The gas fee for these internal transactions is already included in the main transaction (point 1) fee.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. But I already decided to use:
`import "@openzeppelin/contracts/finance/PaymentSplitter.sol";`
After that, I got a bunch of other errors, but that's a completely different story.